# when to use $\mathbb{R}$ notation

Tags: notation

I am in the midst of some writing for school work and couldn't find when is it appropriate to specify the membership of a function. For example, is it appropriate to specify the angular velocity of a rigid body, $\mathbf{\omega} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, or is this redundant as this is obvious?

Comment: Physical observables are always real-valued or real-vector-valued, so I'd say it's redundant.  But if you're ever in any doubt, just put the domain.  It couldn't hurt.

Comment: Never is a bad thing define the domain of a function explicitly. If sometimes we dont show it explicitly it is because it is well-known, so in many contexts it seems unnecessary.

Comment: After some discussion with my lab mates, we arrived at a similar conclusion. For common quantities, it is pedantic; for uncommon quantities, it can be beneficial. On the other hand, sometimes it is field specific...